# Why Visual Studio Code Intellisense does not show text description in workspace with multiple projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have two C# console projects in a Workspace:

[image]

Why Visual Studio Code Intellisense does not show text description in the second project Program.cs file?

First project:

[image]

Second project:

[image]

I have the last Visual Studio Code version:

[image]

Comment: are HelloWorld1 and HelloWord2 separate multiroot workspace roots? If so, please show their .vscode/settings.json files in as minimal a form as reproduces the issue (a [mre])

Comment: @user HelloWorld1 and HelloWorld2 are in the same root folder:  C:\C#\Console\HelloWorld1, C:\C#\Console\HelloWorld2, only C#.code-workspace file is in C# folder. Each .vscode folder has the same default files: launch.json and tasks.json